# How do I make text field to be hidden?

Tags: pdf, itext, field, textfield, hidden

I'd like to create a text field with iTextSharp that is not visible. Here's code I'm using to create a textfield:

```
TextField field = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x, y - h, x + w, y), name);
field.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(bgcolor[0], bgcolor[1], bgcolor[2]);
field.BorderColor = new BaseColor(bordercolor[0], bordercolor[1], bordercolor[2]);
field.BorderWidth = border;
field.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID;
field.Text = text;
writer.AddAnnotation(field.GetTextField());
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `TextField` class has a method named [`setVisibility()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseField.html#setVisibility%28int%29) inherited from its parent, the `BaseField` class. Possible values are:

- `BaseField.VISIBLE`,
- `BaseField.HIDDEN`,
- `BaseField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT`, and
- `BaseField.HIDDEN_BUT_PRINTABLE`.

As you're using iTextSharp, you should look for a `SetVisibility()` method or a `Visibility` property.

Using a render mode as suggested by another person in answer to this question applies to content written to a content stream, XObject or appearance. You are asking to hide a field, and that's something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TEXT_RENDER_MODE_INVISIBLE` but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will still select it - you have been warned!